# How to play a movie on top of a webcam texture

Tags: unity, video

I've been through the Unity docs, searched here, and on stackoverflow; I have not found any good information about using the WebCamTexture for my purposes. So here goes, how do I play a movie asset such as an mp4 clip so that it appears to be on top of the captured webcam image? Lets assume the movie is semi-transparent.

Comment: Can't you just place a MovieTexture on top of the WebCamTexture, using the same coordinates?

Comment: That would probably work for non-mobile devices; but on ios and android I can't use MovieTexture if I'm not mistaken.